# How to track order abort with Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, tracking

I have a 4-step-order-process:

- step 1 (product overview)
- step 2 (shipping)
- step 3 (payment)
- step 4 (complete)

I want to track in which step a customer aborts an order or if he/she completes it.

Used GA tracking code:

```
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

I tried this:

*step1.html*

```
$('input[name="next"]').click(function() {
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
}

if ($('input[name="next"]').data('clicked') !== true) {
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Order', 'Abort', 'Step 1']);
    };
}
```

*step2.html*

```
$('input[name="next"]').click(function() {
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
}

if ($('input[name="next"]').data('clicked') !== true) {
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Order', 'Abort', 'Step 2']);
    };
}
```

*step3.html*

```
$('input[name="next"]').click(function() {
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
}

if ($('input[name="next"]').data('clicked') !== true) {
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Order', 'Abort', 'Step 3']);
    };
}
```

*step4.html*

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Order', 'Complete', 'Step 4']);
```

But it seems that there is not enough time to completely transmit the data to Google as the requests are beeing cancelled. How to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a goal with required steps and you can view the funnel (how many people continue, how many people exit the site, or how many people just go to another page) under the "Funnel Visualization" report.

Comment: Can I also see there on which step a customer aborts an order?

Comment: Yup, by definition you're use case is a funnel. These reports will get you exactly what you need

Comment: Thank you! Anyway, is there a solution going along with my approach?

Comment: What, if all order steps have the same URL and only differ in POST data?

Comment: You can use a virtual page name to differentiate the pages. There is no guarantee if the user's GA call actually can go through before the user leaves if you're doing an unload event.

Comment: Thank you! How does the virtual page name thing work?

Comment: You can pass in your own path to the _trackPageview call: [docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._trackPageview)

Comment: Do I have to define the virtual page names before?

Comment: I'm not sure how you're doing it now, but it's typical to do a `_trackPageview` call with each step of the funnel.= (e.g. each new page the user sees). You'd define the virtual page names then

Comment: So I define the virtual page names with the `_trackPageview` call inherently?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure using `window.onbeforeunload` is the right way? For my knowledge, it will be fired even when your users are moving to the next step (leaving the page), not only when they close the browser.

For you question, perhaps setTimeout() will help here to make the necessary delay in the code execution?

(Anyhow, funnel visualization is the right way.)

Comment: Just see my code to answer your question. ;-)

So, this should work?

`$('input[name="next"]').click(function() {
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
}

if ($('input[name="next"]').data('clicked') !== true) {
    window.onbeforeunload = window.setTimeout(function () {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Order', 'Abort', 'Step 1']);
    }, 1000);
}`